# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, integer, tuples

I am getting the error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" for a specific line in my python code when trying to plot certain values from a csv file, but the error is not consistent from all the plot. Below is the code I am having trouble with and the error pops up for line axs[0].bar(r-(width*2), Ruby[1:, 7], width=width,  color='w', alpha=1).

If I plot "Ruby" separately from the other files it works without error.

Any ideas why python would be reading certain lines as tuples from a csv file in certain plot but not in others?

```
with open("Ruby\Ruby.csv") as file_name:
    Ruby= np.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=",")

with open("Mine Slide\MS.csv") as file_name:
    MS = np.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=",")


dates = ['2021\n03 Oct\n15 Oct', '15 Oct\n27 Oct', '27 Oct\n08 Nov', '08 Nov\n20 Nov', '20 Nov\n02 Dec','2021\n02 Dec\n14 Dec']
ifg= [1,2,3,4,5,6]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
n=6
r=np.arange(n)
width= 0.07
axs[0].bar(r-(width*2), Ruby[1:, 8], width=width,  color='pink', alpha=0.5)
Ruby=axs[0].bar(r-(width*2), Ruby[1:, 4], width=width, label='Ruby Creek',  color='pink', alpha=0.5)
axs[0].bar(r-(width*2), Ruby[1:, 7], width=width,  color='w', alpha=1)
axs[0].bar(r-(width*1), MS[1:7, 8], width=width,  color='r', alpha=0.5)
MS1=axs[0].bar(r-(width*1), MS[1:7, 4], width=width, label='Mine Slide 1',  color='r', alpha=0.5)
axs[0].bar(r-(width*1), MS[1:7, 7], width=width,  color='w', alpha=1)
axs[0].bar(r-(width*0), MS[7:13, 8], width=width,  color='b', alpha=0.5)
MS2=axs[0].bar(r-(width*0), MS[7:13, 4], width=width, label='Mine Slide 2',  color='b', alpha=0.5)
axs[0].bar(r-(width*0), MS[7:13, 7], width=width,  color='w', alpha=1)
R2=axs[0].bar(r+(width*3), MS[25:, 4], width=width, label='Ruby 2',  color='m', alpha=0.5)
axs[0].bar(r+(width*3), MS[25:, 7], width=width,  color='w', alpha=1)
#axs[0].bar_label(Ruby, padding=1, rotation='vertical')
axs[0].bar_label(MS1, padding=1, rotation='vertical')
axs[0].bar_label(R2, padding=1, rotation='vertical')
axs[0].set_ylim(0, 1)
axs[0].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))
axs[0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 6, step=1))
#axs[0].set_xticklabels(('Pre-Failure', 'Pre-Failure', 'Pre-Failure', 'Failure', 'Post-Failure', 'Post-Failure', 'Post-Failure'))
axs[0].set_ylabel('Coherence')
axs[0].set_xlabel('IFG NO.')


axs[1].plot(dates, Ruby[1:, 4], color='pink', label='Ruby Creek')
axs[1].plot(dates, MS[1:7, 4], color='r', label='Mine Slide 1')
axs[1].plot(dates, MS[7:13, 4], color='b', label='Mine Slide 2')
axs[1].plot(dates, MS[25:, 4], color='m', label='Ruby 2')
axs[1].title.set_text('November 2021- Asc- Master Varied-Slides-VV')
axs[1].set_ylim(0, 1)
axs[1].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))
axs[1].set_ylabel('Coherence')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Dates')
axs[1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc="center left")
```

Tried plotting all files separately and and they work without issue